# How to draw a snub dodecahedron?

Tags: drawing

I like to know how to draw a [snub dodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snub_dodecahedron) using just a pencil, compass, marked ruler and calculator (using the calculator to calculate some trigonometric functions, and to measure distances with a ruler), like in [this video](https://www.dearingdraws.com/how-to-draw-dodecahedron-platonic-solids/).

I already know how to draw a dodecahedron, an icosahedron, a cube, etc.

I am skilful with the compass and the ruler, but I can't find any instructions on drawing this solid.

Comment: I removed your comment saying you don't want downvotes: that is completely up to other users. About your question: draw it how? Using linear perspective? In oblique projection?

Comment: @Joachim Like dodecahedron here: https://www.dearingdraws.com/how-to-draw-dodecahedron-platonic-solids/.

Comment: "I can draw anything." than it sounds like you already know how to draw it so go do it. Snark aside not all shapes can be drawn using a compass and ruler. Check [the wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straightedge_and_compass_construction) on that.   I am voting to close because this is requesting a tutorial, and has more to do with higher mathematics than it does with crafting.

Comment: @rebusB Agreed. With both points. The missing step here - based on the linked video - seems to be figuring out how that method can be applied to other solids. And looking at it I'm not even sure if there is a logic to it.

Comment: @rebusB I have written then that "I can draw anything. **But how can I do it?**". I have meant here that I am skilful with the compass and the ruler, but I don't know the instructions on drawing it.

Comment: Just teasing... but there are things that cannot be drawn that way. And elevating the construction to 3d objects extends that. The video works because the underlaying shapes of the solid are constructible with compass. There is no guarantee more complex ones will be...

Comment: Hi User123, I've edited your changes into the original question: you can just use that function to change your question, and don't need to add 'edits'.

Comment: A little late to the party here, but a mathematically-inclined friend and I might be interested in investigating this question. While it's not possible to draw all shapes with a compass and straight-edge (which is the subject of the article linked in the wiki earlier), it sounds like @User123 is willing to use a marked ruler (not just a straight-edge) to produce the drawing, which provides much more freedom/opportunity than just a straight-edge. This is still a non-trivial question, though, so no promises on providing a satisfactory answer. But we'll probably give it a try in about a week!